# How to catch single quote symbol (') into string for JSON.parse?

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x

I get a lot of data from Django into template as:

```
var dataFromServer = JSON.parse('{{ delivery_provider|jsonify }}');
```

Anytime when into Django data presents some symbols ' like this

```
{"id": 1, "company_name": "User's company", "address": null }
```

my javascript code is crashed with error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

because symbol ' have wrong interpretation into string at front side.

How to escape this quote symbols by Python/Django? Or, is exists some solution at the front side?

Comment: Could you provide an example? Because parsing your test data works fine for me if you ditch the `JSON.parse` https://jsfiddle.net/0v4j9qs5/. So try removing `JSON.parse` from your js code and try again

Comment: You need to make sure that the string produced by `{{ delivery_provider|jsonify }}` has all occurrences of `'` replaced with `\'`

Comment: Mikael, i am NOT Python/Django programmer, i don't now how to works with escaped symbols with him

Comment: What is `jsonify`? Note that the [`escapejs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs) filter will escape your quotes correctly, but I don't know how it would interact with that unknown filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`escapejs` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs).
From django docs:

> Escapes characters for use in JavaScript strings.

So, in your case it could be:

```
var dataFromServer = JSON.parse('{{ delivery_provider|jsonify|escapejs }}');
```

Also, if you use [django-jsonify](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jsonify/0.2.1), there is usage example in the docs:

```
var items = {{ items|jsonify }};
```

This means, the author was intended to skip part where you do `JSON.parse` and put object directly to javascript code.